# Overwrite same file using FileWriter

Tags: java, file, filewriter

I want to overwrite the same file. I have some text fields as input in GUI and when i click button (JButton) it should write it to file. if i click it again it should overwrite the content. Currently its overwriting only if click button after closing application and open again but  when i click multiple times in same session , it append it instead of overwriting .Please find below code i tried.

```
btnSetupProcess.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String batchFilePath = createBatchFileAndGetPath(); 
            }
        });
```

```
private String createBatchFileAndGetPath() {
File newFile = new File("Test.bat");
            try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(newFile, false))  {
                //newFile.createNewFile();
                writer.write( batchFileContent.toString());
                return newFile.getAbsolutePath();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();

return "";          }
}
```

Comment: Where is `batchFileContent` coming from? Is it possible that the content is getting appended to that variable itself?

Comment: thanks , i was doing silly mistake :( it was coming from StringBuilder , which i did not initialized again .